# LibertinusT1math printing unusual characters in Beamer

Tags: beamer

Using LibertinusT1math in Beamer, several characters (e.g., circle, `\times`) are not displayed and some (parentheses) are displayed incorrectly.  The following code shows the problem.  Just uncomment the `\usepackage{libertinust1math}` line to see the output with and without the errors.  I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.  The problem doesn't occur using the article class.

```
\documentclass[12pt,presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{libertinust1math}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Linear Regression}

 \begin{itemize}
 \item first
 \item second
 \end{itemize}

\[ Y_{E} = b_{0e} + (b_{1e} \cdot x_{1}) + (b_{2e} \cdot x_{2}) + (b_{3e} \cdot
x_{3})\ldots (b_{ne} \cdot x_{n}) + e\]

Degree classification \(=(IQ \times 0.23) +
(Motiv \times 0.36) + (Grade \times 0.54) + (Supp \times 0.14) + 20.3\)

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the classoption `professionalfonts`?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but you should not use math mode for multi-letter words such as "Grade"

Comment: x-post: https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/da3vap/libertinust1math_printing_unusual_characters_in/

Comment: The duplicate refers to MinionPro, but the problem and solutions are the same.

Comment: @RalfStubner  Thanks for your suggestion.  That does work to a certain extent.  One unusual effect is that the bullet points are smaller than the standard version.